# Using MVT to prove $\ln(x) < \sqrt{x} \quad \forall x > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

My lecture notes:

> For all $x > 0$, $\ln(x) < \sqrt{x}$, which can be proven using the mean value theorem.

I've tried considering the intervals $(0, \infty)$ and $(0, x)$ and the function $f(x) = \ln(x) - \sqrt{x}$, but I haven't been able to get anywhere.

---

Out of curiosity, are there any other neat ways to show the statement is true (besides comparing derivatives)? I (believe I) managed to use the limit definition of $e$ to prove $\ln(x) < 2 \sqrt{x}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you know that $\sqrt 4 - \ln 4>0.$ Let $f(x) = \sqrt x - \ln x.$ For $x>4,$ for some number $c$ between $4$ and $x$ you have
$$
\frac{(\sqrt x - \ln x)-(\sqrt 4-\ln 4)}{x-4} = f'(c) = \frac 1 {2\sqrt c} - \frac 1 c = \frac{\sqrt c - 2}{2c} >0.
$$
Since the denominator is positive and the fraction as a whole is positive, the numerator must be positive, so $\sqrt x > \ln x.$

For $x<4$ you need other methods. It's easy for $x\le 1$ since then $\ln x\le 0.$

Answer (score 2):

For function $\sqrt{x} -\ln(x)$ we have minimum in point $ 4 $ and it equal $  2-2\ln2 >0$.